# What correlation coefficient should I compute if I have a dichotomous variable and an ordinal variable with tied ranks?

Tags: correlation, binary-data

I am not sure if I will compute the rank-biserial correlation coefficient since the formula assumes that there are no tied ranks.

To provide further context, here is my data:

[image: To provide further context, here is my data:]

Note: The dichotomous variable is on the left column.